# Error response from daemon: lease "moby-image-sha256:c274..": not found

Tags: docker

Ran the command docker-compose up -d
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P02Ss.png)
got this error : Error response from daemon: lease "moby-image-sha256:c2740b69f111bd711c867e337c12bab4b3d720c987e0d09549fe95e6badc6ba8": not found

No idea what this means. I am on a M1.This is my docker files :

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  telikos-activityplanworkflow-service:
    container_name: telikos-activityplanworkflow-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      ##----Dependent images-----------
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      mongo:
        condition: service_started
    ##---Ports-------------
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    ##---Environment variables------------
    environment:
      - server.port=8080
      - kafkabootstrapservers=broker:9092
  ##-----------------------------------------
  #----docker-images------------------------------------------------------


  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeperap
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: brokerap
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z localhost 29092 || exit -1
      start_period: 25s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10


  mongo:
    container_name: mongoap
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/test --quiet
      start_period: 40s
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://admin:password@mongo:27017/
```

DockerFile :

```
FROM bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:17
RUN apk add curl
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/telikos-activityplanworkflow-service.jar /app/
ADD --chown=15000:15000 'https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar' opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar", "-jar", "telikos-activityplanworkflow-service.jar"]
```

I was trying to run kafka and zookeeper in docker using the docker file above. I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 5):

That error looks like it could be related to the new containerd image storage integration being added in Docker Desktop.

First attempt to toggle the support for this feature following the steps from [docker's docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/containerd/#enabling-the-containerd-image-store-feature):

> 1. Navigate to Settings.
> 2. Select the Experimental features tab.
> 3. Next to Use containerd for pulling and storing images, select the checkbox.

If changing that solves your issue, then please follow up on the [roadmap issue 371](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/371) where they are tracking the progress of this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

In general, leases are resources in containerd which are created by clients and are used to reference other resources such as snapshots and content, as stated in [this link](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/garbage-collection.md).

To solve the problem, you should cleanup your environment. So delete the containers you have with `docker rm <container>` commands, delete the images with `docker rmi <image>` and then remove the leases from containerd's root directory `/var/lib/container`.